# How to send lat lng values in backround to sever for every 1min?

Tags: android

I am developing one application in that i have to send lat lng values to server for every 1 min when i click on start buttton and if i click stop button it have to stop sending values to server.I tried using runnable its working but some time its not working .I dont know it is correct process or not,please give me any solution for this

public class MonitoringActivity extends Activity  {

```
private String lat;
private String lng;
private double latd;
private double lngd;
private Button startOrDelBtn;
 //Runnable myHandlerTask;
private static Runnable mHandlerTask;
protected static final long INTERVAL = 2000*30;

protected static Handler mHandler;
private String val;
private int NOTIFICTION_ID=1;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
MediaPlayer player ;
//private int flag_Out = 2;
private int flag_In = 1;
private String shedForPanicVal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
     bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
     bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
     bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_jamlocation);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring);

    startOrDelBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.monitorId);




     mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
        {

             @Override 
             public void run() {
                  mHandler = new Handler();
                  mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
                  String checkShValForPanic = SharedDB.getValue(MonitoringActivity.this);

                  if(checkShValForPanic=="2"){
                 // new SendDataAsync(MonitoringActivity.this,"2",latd,lngd).execute();
                      Log.e("Panic", "status 2");

                    //  SharedDB.setValue(MonitoringActivity.this, "2");
                      new SendLatLngAsync(MonitoringActivity.this,"2",latd,lngd).execute();
                  }
                  else{
                 // else if(checkShValForPanic=="1"){
                    //new SendDataAsync(MonitoringActivity.this,"1",latd,lngd).execute();
                      Log.e("Non Panic", "status 1");
                    //  SharedDB.setValue(MonitoringActivity.this, "1");
                    //  SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this, flag_In);
                      new SendLatLngAsync(MonitoringActivity.this,"1",latd,lngd).execute();
                  }
                 // }

             }

        };
        int runFlag = SharedDB.getFlag(MonitoringActivity.this);
        // if flag is not there i shared preference 
        if(runFlag==0){
            Log.e("NEW", "ACTIVITY");
        SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this, flag_In);
        mHandlerTask.run();
        }
        else{
            Log.e("ALREADY", "EXIST ACTIVITY");
        }


        // Notification Initialization



}

public void stopMonitoring(View v){
    v.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    String startOrDeText = startOrDelBtn.getText().toString().trim();


    try {
        if(startOrDeText.equals("Stop")){
            startOrDelBtn.setText("Start");
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
         Log.e("STOPPED", "BUTTON");
        // new SendDataAsync(MonitoringActivity.this,"0",latd,lngd).execute();
         //SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this, flag_Out);
         SharedDB.removeFlag(MonitoringActivity.this);
         SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this,0);
         SharedDB.setValue(MonitoringActivity.this, SharedDB.defaultVal);
         new SendLatLngAsync(MonitoringActivity.this,"0",latd,lngd).execute();
         notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICTION_ID);
    }
        else if(startOrDeText.equals("Start")){
            //SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this, flag_Out);
             Log.e("STARTED", "BUTTON");
            startOrDelBtn.setText("Stop");
             SharedDB.removeFlag(MonitoringActivity.this);
             SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this,flag_In);
             SharedDB.setValue(MonitoringActivity.this, "1");
            mHandlerTask.run();
           notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICTION_ID,mBuilder.build());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void panicReport(View v){

    val="2";
    try {
        startOrDelBtn.setText("Stop");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
        SharedDB.removeFlag(MonitoringActivity.this);
        SharedDB.startOrStopShare(MonitoringActivity.this,flag_In);
        SharedDB.setValue(MonitoringActivity.this, "2");
        mHandlerTask.run();
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICTION_ID,mBuilder.build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class SendLatLngAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private HttpPost httpPost;
    private HttpGet httpGet;
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> arryPair;
    private DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    private String response;
    private Context mContext;
    private double longitute;
    private double latitute;
    private String mStatus;
    private String lati;
    private String longi;
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(MonitoringActivity.this);
    double Lat =   gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    double Lng =   gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    private int responsecode;
    private boolean isConnectedToInternet;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public SendLatLngAsync(Context context,String status,double lat,double lng){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mStatus = status;
        this.latitute = lat;
        this.longitute = lng;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MonitoringActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        isConnectedToInternet=CheckNetClass.isConnectedToInternet(MonitoringActivity.this);*/

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Log.e("Current In Async", Lat+"  "+Lng);
        String lat1= Double.toString(Lat);
        String lng1= Double.toString(Lng);
        /*GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(this.mContext);
        String latg = Double.toString(tracker.getLatitude());
        String lang = Double.toString(tracker.getLongitude());
        Log.e("FROM TRACKER", latg+" "+lang);*/
         httpClient =new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(UrlConstant.SEND_PANIC);
        //httpGet = new HttpGet(UrlConstant.SEND_PANIC_FOR_GUEST);
        try {
            //Log.e("LATI", lati+longi);
             arryPair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             arryPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",lat1));
             arryPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",lng1));
             arryPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("trackid","Durga"));
             arryPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", mStatus));
             httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arryPair));

            HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
             HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
             response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8 );

             responsecode = responsePOST.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
             Log.e("STATUS CODE", ""+responsecode);
             Log.i("SomeTag",
                        "doInBackGround done at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
             Log.e("MONITOR", response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        /*pDialog.dismiss();
        if(isConnectedToInternet)
        if(responsecode==200){

        }
        else{

            GetAlertDialog.getDialog(MonitoringActivity.this, GetAlertDialog.serverdown);

        }
        else{

            GetAlertDialog.getDialog(MonitoringActivity.this, GetAlertDialog.networkfailure);
        }

        //Toast.makeText(MonitoringActivity.this, "SUCCESS", 100).show();  */
    }

  }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MonitoringActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

         mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("TRACKING")
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.panic)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .setSound(uri)
                                    .setContentIntent(pIntent);


        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICTION_ID,mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is not working? What did you found out when debugging your code?

Comment: @Rvdk please tell me is it right process?

Comment: You have to write a `Service` which runs in background

Answer (score 3):

I Solved my question using with service in backgroung

```
private HttpPost httpPost;
private HttpGet httpGet;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> arryPair;
private DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
private String response;
private int responsecode;
private double Lat;
private double Lng;
private double lat;
private double lng;
private int status;
//private String status;
private static Runnable mHandlerTask;
protected static final long INTERVAL = 1000*10;
protected static Handler mHandler;


 public SendLatLngService() {
 }
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
 }
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //status= intent.getStringExtra("status");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


}
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




     mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
        {

             @Override 
             public void run() {


                  mHandler = new Handler();
                  mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
                  new asyncServ().execute();
             }
          };
          mHandlerTask.run();

 }

  @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  // Perform your long running operations here.
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

  @Override
 public void onDestroy() {

      mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
      Log.e("DESTROYED", "CALLED");
      new asyncServ().execute();
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
  @Override
public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return super.bindService(service, conn, flags);
}

  public class asyncServ extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
      public asyncServ(){
      GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(SendLatLngService.this);
         Lat =   gpsTracker.getLatitude();
         Lng =   gpsTracker.getLongitude();
      }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String lat1= Double.toString(Lat);
            String lng1= Double.toString(Lng);
            httpClient =new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(UrlConstant.SEND_PANIC);
            Log.e("Status", status+"");
            try {
                //Log.e("LATI", lati+longi);
                 arryPair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 arryPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",lat1));
                 arryPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",lng1));

                 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arryPair));

                HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                 HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                 response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8 );


                 Log.i("SomeTag",
                            "doInBackGround done at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
               //  Log.e("MONITOR", response);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

  You can call startService(intent) if you want to start service and i you want to stop then you          
  call stopService(intent) from your activity     you must add service name in the manifest file
```